# Slack Button Response Data / Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack

So I am making an app for slack where users can click a yes or no button. Basically the buttons work and the script sends a message back once the button has been pressed. However, I can not figure out how to get the data from the button (which button has been pressed). I have been looking for a solution online but I can't find one anywhere.

My code:

Buttons:

```
{
                                            "name": "yes",
                                            "text": "Yes",
                                            "type": "button",
                                            "value": "yes"
                                          },
                                         {
                                            "name": "no",
                                            "text": "No",
                                            "type": "button",
                                            "value": "no"
                                         }
```

Button response code:

```
function doPost(req) {
       Logger.log("doPost: " + JSON.stringify(req));

  var payload = JSON.parse(req.parameter.payload);

  Logger.log(payload);


   var replyMessage = {
    replace_original: true,
    response_type: "in_channel",
    text: "Thank you for submitting your response" + payload.yes,
  };
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(replyMessage)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out :) leaving the post up in case anyone finds it interesting

```
  var payload = JSON.parse(req.parameter.payload);
  var text = payload.actions[0].name;
```